# Display WooCommerce Attributes (field names) that are empty as well

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I am trying to list all attributes (filled in or not) in WooCommerce.

With this code:

`//show attributes after summary in product single view
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {
    //template for this is in storefront-child/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php
    global $product;
    echo $product->list_attributes();
}, 25);`

But this only shows filled attributes and I would like to show them all.

Any help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) in WooCommerce 3+ **`WC_Product list_attributes()`** method is deprecated. Instead you should use the function [**`wc_display_product_attributes($product)`**](http://wc_display_product_attributes) …

2) You can't save an attribute with empty values in a product...

So may be what you are looking at is to get all existing Product attributes. if it's the case, here is the way to do it:

```
function wc_get_all_attributes(){
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies";

    $wc_attributes = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT attribute_id, attribute_name, attribute_label
        FROM $table_name
    ");

    return $wc_attributes;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**USAGE:**

Then you can use it in multiple ways in any php file of your active theme:

For example to list the attribute names (Labels):

```
$all_attributes = wc_get_all_attributes();

foreach( $all_attributes as $attribute_obj ){
    echo '<p>'.$attribute_obj->attribute_label.'</p>';
}
```

This will output all existing product attributes.

In each **`$attribute_obj`** object, you will be able to get:

```
$attribute_obj->attribute_id; // ID
$attribute_obj->attribute_name; // SLUG
$attribute_obj->attribute_label; // LABEL (displayed name)
```